# ito lemma to a stochasitic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

$dS_t = \mu_tS_tdt+\sigma_t S_tdB_t$, if define $X(t)=\int_0^t \mu(s)-1/2\sigma^2(s)ds + \int_0^t \sigma(s)dB(s）$,then the solution of S is $S_t = S_0 \exp(X_t)$.

now define $A_t = \int_0^tS_udu$, $Y_t = A_t/S_t$.

prove:$dY_t = (1-\mu_tY_t)dt + \sigma_tY_tdB_t$

I saw this proposition in a paper without proof, but I cannot prove it myself, especially use ito to $A_t$, I haven't calculated the problem of this nested form before.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you sure the claim is correct?

Comment: not too sure, so can d Y_t be calculated? maybe not this form.

Comment: The answer should be $dY_t=(1+(\sigma_t^2-\mu_t)Y_t)dt-\sigma_tY_tdW_t$. Please check again if the details of your problem match your claim or if a correction is needed.

Comment: or dA_t? or d(1/t A_t)? I want to know any of it?

Comment: can you show me the details?

Comment: You should provide more details first: why you claim $(1-\mu_tY_t)dt+\sigma_tY_tdW_t$, and importantly what have you tried (so that an optimal answer may be provided by the community).

Answer (score 1):

Another, more direct, way to approach the problem is to Ito the multidimensional Ito formula.

Consider the function $f(x,y):=x/y$ and apply Ito in two dimensions, i.e.

$$
df = \bigg( \partial_t f + \mu_x \partial_xf+\mu_y\partial_y f+\frac{\sigma_{x}^{2}}{2}\partial_{xx}f +\frac{\sigma_{y}^{2}}{2}\partial_{yy}f + \sigma_x \sigma_y \rho \, \partial_{xy} f\bigg)dt + \sigma_x \partial_xf dB_{t}^{1} +  \sigma_y \partial_yf dB_{t}^{2}
$$

where $B^i$ are two correlated BM with correlation $\rho$.

In our case then

$$
dY_t=(1+(\sigma_{t}^{2} - \mu_t)Y_t)dt - \sigma_t Y_t dB_t
$$

Comment: While this approach would be my choice, I don't understand why you set up correlated brownian motions. My system of choice would be: $$\begin{bmatrix}
dS_t\\
dA_t
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_tS_t\\
S_t
\end{bmatrix}dt+
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_tS_t&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
dW_t\\
dB_t
\end{bmatrix}$$ where $W,B$ are independent. The function would then be $f(s,a)=s/a$.

Comment: *$f(s,a)=a/s$ of course

Comment: @Snoop the formula was meant to be as general as possible also as a future referrnce. in solving the exercise I did consider the dynimics you provided

Comment: Ok, but if $\rho=0$ then the cross-term derivative disappears, and this is not the case in general when we consider an arbitrary system.. it works here in this case because cross terms have no volatility. Also why are there no second order partial derivative terms? I'm not entirely following. I appreciate your patience

Comment: i answer the second question first: no second derivatives because I forgot the subscript (where I have $\sigma_{i}^{2}$ those are second derivatives). thanks for spotting that, I edited to correct the mistake. In this case $\rho = 0$ and the formula simplifies but if they are correlated that's the 2D Ito formula one should use. In this sense I meant "general"

Answer (score 0):

You have $dA_t=S_t\,dt$.

Division can look ugly, look at the multiplication $A_t=S_tY_t$, with the trial $dY_t=adt+bdB$. Then
\begin{align}
S_t\,dt=dA_t&=Y_tdS_t+S_tdY_t+d\langle S,Y\rangle_t  \\
&=S_tY_t(μ_t\,dt+σ_t\,dB_t)+S_t(a_t\,dt+b_t\,dB_t)+S_tσ_t\,b_t\,dt \\
dt &= (μ_tY_t+a_t+σ_t\,b_t)\,dt + (σ_tY_t+b_t)\,dB_t
\end{align}

Comparing coefficients gives $b_t=-σ_tY_t$ and $a_t=1-μ_tY_t+σ_t^2Y_t$.

---

Let's try alternatively for, $Y_t=S_t/A_t$.

Then repeating the same as above gives for $S=AY$
\begin{align}
S_t(μ_t\,dt+σ_t\,dB_t)=dS_t&=A_tdY_t+Y_tdA_t+d⟨A,Y⟩_t \\
&=A_t(a_tdt+b_tdB_t)+Y_tS_t\,dt+0  \\
Y_t(μ_t\,dt+σ_t\,dB_t)&=(a_t+Y_t^2)\,dt+b_t\,dB_t
\end{align}
so that $a_t=Y_tμ_t-Y_t^2=Y_t(μ_t-Y_t)$ and $b_t=σ_tY_t$.

This gives the SDE
$$
dY_t=Y_t(μ_t-Y_t)\,dt+σ_tY_t\,dB_t,
$$
still not the claimed equation.

Comment: as your first method in the last step, by comparing the coefficients, is the equation like this?: 
$$\mu_tY_t+a_t+\sigma_tb_t=1;\quad \sigma_t+b_t=0$$?

it seems from the secend equation that $b_t=-\sigma_t$?


another question: why your two methods derived different result? Is thy equal?

Comment: Oh, I notice it, it seems at the forth line $(\sigma_tY_t+b_t)dB_t$ could be right. But I am still confused that is these two methods equal? why not the same result?

Comment: @WangJing They are not equal because there's a small mistake in the second approach since he computed the Ito formula for a different process (inverted numerator and denominator in the correct definition of $Y_t$).

Comment: oh, thanks, got it.

Comment: @finch : That was intentional. As the original formula did not fit the claimed result, I tried a different formula for $Y$, which got rid of the $\sigma$ in the trend coefficient, but still is markedly different from the claimed formula.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Makes sense